# Raycast that ignore certain Game Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`PlayerController` Class

```
public LayerMask groundLayer;

    void LookRotation()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, groundLayer))
    {
        destination = new Vector3(hitInfo.point.x, transform.position.y, hitInfo.point.z);
        //Look at mouse position
        transform.LookAt(destination);
    }
}
```

I am having an issue getting my Raycast to either ignore my player or only detect the ground. In the actual unity inspector I have set the `LayerMask` to be my `Ground Layer` and with my current code it will only detect the ground if it is in the `Ground Layer` although the player will still interfere with the Raycast even though it is not in the `Ground Layer`. I need the Raycast to completely ignore the player and even though this is achieved by adding the player to the `Ignore Raycast` layer, I can't do that because the player will need to be detected by different Raycasts. all of this code occurs in my `PlayerController` script as it is used to determine my players rotation, I am unsure if that may be the reason the player interferes with the Raycast. Cheers in advance!

Comment: Thanks joe, I figured out my second question.

Comment: great!  see you around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Are you using the layer MASK the correct way?

It's more like this ...

```
int layerMaskYourHero = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("YourHero");
```

and then

```
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(
        laserEmittingPoint.position, Vector2.left,
        castLength,
        layerMaskYourHero);
```

(2) Say, you're using the physics matrix right ?

[image]

go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics